# Error accessing blocks in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-blocks

I have migrated my Drupal 7 website to a server, and now I can't access the blocks via the admin menu; all I get is a white screen. It was working perfectly in my localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get a white screen vs an access denied screen, the problem is a fatal PHP error, most likely a module or custom code fails when it's called about which blocks is provides.

You can get info about the error in your web server's error log.